# Esc event listener is not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have added keypress listener and that's not work.
When the listener of "click" is called - is working perfect.

This is the code:

```
var closeSave = document.getElementById("closeSave");
    closeSave.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
    closeSave.addEventListener("keypress", closeWindowByEsc);

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        var closeWindow = function() {
            saveModal.style.display = "none";
            loadModal.style.display = "none";
        }

    var closeWindowByEsc = function(){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '27'){
      closeWindow(e);
    }
  }
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: use the keydown event instead of keypress.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that declaring `var func = function () { ...` hoists the `var func;` part to the top of the scope, but `func` is not defined as `function () { ...` until that line is reached. So when you attach the event handlers, this is essentially what's happening:

```
var closeSave = document.getElementById("closeSave");
var closeWindow;
var closeWindowByEsc;

// here, closeWindow and closeWindowByEsc are `undefined`
closeSave.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
closeSave.addEventListener("keypress", closeWindowByEsc);

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
closeWindow = function() {
  saveModal.style.display = "none";
  loadModal.style.display = "none";
}

closeWindowByEsc = function(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode == '27') {
    closeWindow();
  }
}
```

You can do two things to solve this:

move the `addEventListener()`s below the instantiation:

```
var closeSave = document.getElementById("closeSave");

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
var closeWindow = function() {
  saveModal.style.display = "none";
  loadModal.style.display = "none";
}

var closeWindowByEsc = function(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode == '27') {
    closeWindow();
  }
}

closeSave.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
closeSave.addEventListener("keypress", closeWindowByEsc);
```

Or you can use a function statement which hoists the instantiation to the top of the scope, rather than a function expression:

```
var closeSave = document.getElementById("closeSave");

closeSave.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
closeSave.addEventListener("keypress", closeWindowByEsc);

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
function closeWindow() {
  saveModal.style.display = "none";
  loadModal.style.display = "none";
}

function closeWindowByEsc(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode == '27') {
    closeWindow();
  }
}
```

Comment: But he says that click event handler is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the event `e` to your function.

```
var closeSave = document.getElementById("closeSave");
closeSave.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
closeSave.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == '27'){
        closeWindow();
    }
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
function closeWindow() {
    saveModal.style.display = "none";
    loadModal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Passing it to the function isn't doing any good if the function isn't using it.

Comment: He's referring to the `closeSave` `"keypress"` event handler, not the `closeWindow()` function.

Comment: The function is using it

Comment: @Sid24, JBC was referring to the fact that you call `closeWindow(e)` instead of `closeWindow()` within the event handler, even though `closeWindow()` doesn't use an event object. But that has nothing to do with answering the question, it's just pointless to pass the event object.

Comment: I didn't notice that because he says that click event handler works fine so i assumed that part is correct.

Comment: Also i don't know why he is using e.which, .which is for jQuery objects. We don't know if he has included jQuery or not.

Comment: @Sid24 [wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which). It's deprecated, but still the most widely supported attribute for determining what key is pressed, for outdated browsers like IE.